# access to property in external file works in controller but not in domain class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a property set in an external application.properties file and find that I can access it in the controller but not in the domain class. I'm using SpringBoot 1.1.9 and groovy and code snippets listed below.

Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

--john

```
//Application class used to startup    
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

//Controller - property is injected
@RestController
class CityController {
    @Value( '${sample.property}' )
    String stringTemplate

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index(HttpServletResponse response) {
       return String.format(stringTemplate, 'world')
   }
}

//Domain class - property does not seem to be injected
@Component
public class City {
    @Value( '${sample.property}' )
    String stringTemplate

    String toString() {
        return String.format(stringTemplate, 'world')
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you print whole configuration?

Comment: You put `@Component` on your `City` but is it really managed by Spring? How do you create an instance of it?

Comment: I thought it was created by virtue of the @ComponentScan annotation used in the main class.